# Windows Azure ConflictError : The specified DNS name is already taken

Tags: windows, azure

I keep getting this error: "ConflictError : The specified DNS name is already taken." though i am pretty sure that i gave different cloud services name and VM name. How to avoid this error? Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: What's the name you're giving?

Comment: This error is confusing at first.  This open issue might provide some insight... https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/653

Answer (score 0):

How to avoid the error?  Use a different DNS name :)

Remember that all services in Azure share the same .cloudapp.net (or .websites.net) domain so it could be some other user who is using that DNS name.  But ultimately the .cloudapp.net DNS name is largely irrelevant since you should be setting up your own custom domain and using CNAME to point to the Azure domain.